# Handling slope sliding in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using a Raycast to slide down steep slopes (with a CharacterController), object types like cylinders make the sliding really inconsistent and the player slides when they should not, because the curvatures of spheres, cylinders, etc, all have many great angles which trigger sliding. Is there a workaround for this or is it the only solution to use layer masks and manually add layers to individual game objects?

I have tried so many things like using Vector3.Cross for the slide direction, Vector3.ProjectOnPlane, and also a SphereCast but none of them so far have solved the problem. I've also come across over a dozen videos and posts online that have slope sliding and they all have the same issue.

On a bumpy uneven surface such as a hill, the player shouldn't be sliding on that slope which has many, many short bumps that contain slopes which are 0.01f in length, if that makes sense, because then the slide stutters/stops a lot.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out rayHit, 5f))
{
    Vector3 slopeNormal = hit.normal;

    Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(slopeNormal, Vector3.up);
    Vector3 slideDir = Vector3.Cross(cross, slopeNormal);

    if (Vector3.Angle(hit.normal, Vector3.up) > 65f) // 65f is slope limit
    {
        isSliding = true; 
        
    }
}

if (isSliding)
{
    controller.Move(slideDir * 5f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: have you considered just using physics materials?